# How do I create a TWebFrame dynamically from code and show it?

Tags: delphi, tframe, tms-web-core

So basically I have a TMS Web Core App and I've created a `TWebFrame` with some random components on it. I want to dynamically create this frame and show it on my main form, but whenever I try to do this, I just see a blank frame without any of the components on it.

Here's my frame:

[image: Delphi TWebFrame with random components]

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, JS, Web, WEBLib.Graphics, WEBLib.Controls,
  WEBLib.Forms, WEBLib.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, WEBLib.StdCtrls, Vcl.Controls, WEBLib.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrameDemo = class(TWebFrame)
    WebLabel1: TWebLabel;
    WebPanel1: TWebPanel;
    WebLabel2: TWebLabel;
    WebMemo1: TWebMemo;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrameDemo: TFrameDemo;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

The way I am trying to create it is simply by creating it as you would in VCL or FMX. Here's a simple example where I'm doing it from the `OnCreate` event on the main form:

```
procedure TFormMain.WebFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aFrame: TWebFrame;
begin
  aFrame := TFrameDemo.Create(Application);
  aFrame.Name := 'MyFrame';
  aFrame.Visible := True;
  aFrame.Parent := FormMain;
  aFrame.Align := alClient;
end;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The frame is created, but it's empty. You can see that by inspecting the DOM via the browser:

[image: TMS Web Core Delphi project in the browser]

Why is the frame empty? Why is it not creating the components on the frame? What is the correct way to dynamically create a TWebFrame in TMS Web Core with Delphi?

Comment: Are you working with or _for_ TMS? All your recent questions and answers kind of advertize TMS...

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, I've been working a lot with TMS lately. Busy playing with TMS Web Core and learning how it works. Not advertising, just posting questions/answers that I struggled or battled with that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to call the `LoadFromForm` function on the created frame:

```
procedure TFormMain.WebFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aFrame: TWebFrame;
begin
  aFrame := TFrameDemo.Create(Application);
  aFrame.Name := 'MyFrame';
  aFrame.Visible := True;
  aFrame.Parent := FormMain;
  aFrame.Align := alClient;

  aFrame.LoadFromForm; // This is needed otherwise it won't create and show components on the frame
end.
```

If you don't call `aFrame.LoadFromForm` after the frame has been created, then it won't create any of the sub-components on the frame.